# Val_accuracy and Accuracy with constant value independent of compile model - Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have a private dataset with 170 images divided into 4 categories (I know it's not much), in each of the 4 categories I have about 30-40 images.

I'm trying to make a network that can predict which image is being inserted into a future app.
But my model never changes the Val_accuracy, I've tried everything, the value always stays at 0.2941 after the first epoch run.

Note that the other values ​​change, even a little, however, only val_accuracy and accuracy remain eternally fixed at 0.2941:

```
Epoch 1/10
46/46 [==============================] - 10s 209ms/step - loss: 1.3859 - accuracy: 0.4338 - val_loss: 1.3861 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
Epoch 2/10
46/46 [==============================] - 10s 206ms/step - loss: 1.3852 - accuracy: 0.4338 - val_loss: 1.3860 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
Epoch 3/10
46/46 [==============================] - 10s 205ms/step - loss: 1.3899 - accuracy: 0.4265 - val_loss: 1.3859 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
Epoch 4/10
46/46 [==============================] - 10s 205ms/step - loss: 1.3908 - accuracy: 0.4265 - val_loss: 1.3857 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
Epoch 5/10
46/46 [==============================] - 10s 206ms/step - loss: 1.3830 - accuracy: 0.4338 - val_loss: 1.3856 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
Epoch 6/10
46/46 [==============================] - 10s 205ms/step - loss: 1.5876 - accuracy: 0.4265 - val_loss: 1.3855 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
Epoch 7/10
46/46 [==============================] - 10s 206ms/step - loss: 1.3817 - accuracy: 0.4338 - val_loss: 1.3854 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
Epoch 8/10
46/46 [==============================] - 10s 206ms/step - loss: 1.3810 - accuracy: 0.4338 - val_loss: 1.3852 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
Epoch 9/10
46/46 [==============================] - 9s 203ms/step - loss: 1.3804 - accuracy: 0.4338 - val_loss: 1.3851 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
Epoch 10/10
46/46 [==============================] - 9s 205ms/step - loss: 1.3797 - accuracy: 0.4338 - val_loss: 1.3850 - val_accuracy: 0.2941
```

Below are some important parameters of my current network.

```
# Real size of original image
    batch_size = 3
    img_height = 280
    img_width = 280

# train_ds and val_ds

    train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="training",
        seed=123,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size
    )

    Output:
    Found 170 files belonging to 4 classes.
    Using 136 files for training.

    val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="validation",
        seed=123,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size
    )
    Output:
    Found 170 files belonging to 4 classes.
    Using 34 files for validation.
```

And... my model:

```
num_classes = 4

    model = Sequential([
      layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
      layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
      layers.MaxPooling2D(),  
      layers.Dropout(0.2),
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

I've tried increasing the number of neurons, increasing the layers, switching to SGD instead of Adam, etc, etc, etc.
I've used data augmentation, nothing has changed, always stagnant at 0.2941

Below my current structure, remembering that each folder has an average of 30-40 imgs:

[image: Folder with my all classes]

And lastly, my model compiles:

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: In my deduction your model isn't learning at all. You have to use transfer-learning as your model is too small and you have very few parameters.

Comment: I also have this suspicion, unfortunately I think there is only this way out, thank you